# React navigation TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate')

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Im trying to use navigation on one of my buttons in my float button. All the code is inside my class.
And I get this error:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating
> 'navigation.navigate')

Ive done the same thing in another class-component and it works fine, but i dont know why i get this issue here?

In my render i have:

```
render = () => {

const { navigation } = this.props;
<View style={{ position: "absolute", alignItems: "center" }}>
  
    <Animated.View
      style={{
        position: "absolute",
        left: thermometerX,
        top: thermometerY,
      }}
    >
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.secondaryButton}
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Test1")}
        
      >
        <MaterialCommunityIcons
          name="emoticon-happy-outline"
          size={24}
          color="#FFF"
        />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </Animated.View>
 </View>
```

}

Comment: What is the shape of the `navigation` object you are receiving from props? it seems like the `navigate` attribute does not exist on the `navigation` props ?

Comment: It says its empty but I dont know why? My other class component works fine and it takes props just like this one

Comment: Where does this component locate in your project structure? Is it under `<NavigationContainer/>` tree